# Как отобразить лишь один компонент при вызове события onClick?

Tags: reactjs

Есть несколько элементов , в которых в свою очередь содержится элемент, который рендерится при изменении состояния на true. Проблема в том, что когда состояние становится true, то рендерятся все компоненты, которые зависят от этого состояния.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы при изменении состояния рендерился лишь один компонент (на родителя которого кликнули) без создания события onclick для каждого компонента?

Код:

```
class Deck extends React.Component {constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  cardDetails: false
};
// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this); }
onClick() {
this.setState({
  cardDetails: true,
}, function() {console.log('cardDetails: ' + this.state.cardDetails + '. This.onclick: ' + this.onClick)});}render() {
return (
  <div className="deck-container">
    <div className="chosen-cards">
      <CardHistory  onClick={this.onClick}>
        {this.state.cardDetails ? <CardDetails  /> : null}
      </CardHistory>
      <CardHistory onClick={this.onClick}>
        {this.state.cardDetails ? <CardDetails /> : null}
      </CardHistory> </div></div> );}}
ReactDOM.render(<Deck></Deck>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Ну да, можно, сделать "cardDetails" состоянием конкретного кусочка, ане всей стопки, т.е. вынести логику показа-непоказа CardDetails в зону ответственности компонента CardHistory

Comment: Также можно пронумеровать карты и сделать состоянием деки массив номеров развернутых карт, но если вам не нужно запоминать где-то на сервере или в сторадже что развернуто, что - нет, то это здесь уже не оч.